# OpenGL ES Android: why does my point cloud fade during rotate

Tags: android, opengl-es

I load an STL mesh, draw it correctly (using GL_TRIANGLES), rotate nicely, change colour, the lights stay in position while the mesh moves, everything is great. Then I switch off the triangles and display just the vertices (using GL_POINTS), now when I rotate (and even when I display the triangles and the vertices together) the points seem to fade out as I rotate - as if they are lit from only one side.

Does this ring any bells with anyone?

Thanks for any help.

Baz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It maybe just a perception artefact. If you still got lighting on, the points are of course lit like the triangle vertices (depending on their normals), meaning they actually have an orientation, even if this is not intuitive for points. So they may get darker or brighter when rotating them into/away from the light. It's just that this change seems more evident, because you don't have the other surface points to fill the gaps and compensate for the dimming. Try disabling lighting and they should keep their color when rotating.

Comment: The weird thing is that the lights stay in place as the model rotates (the viewer has a light positioned over each shoulder as you look at the scene), but the points appear as if the light moves around the origin with the rotating scene, hence I'm seeing the 'back' of the points (the apparently less well lit side). Also I can't turn the lights off because sometimes the points and triangles are seen together. All very confusing.

Comment: @Baz When the light stays in place (relative to the camera), and the points rotate, then they are lit differently. It's not that you see their unlit faces, but they turn their faces away from the light. Don't forget, when using lighting, points also have an orientation, defined by their normal. So when they face away from you (the light), of course they get dimmer. Maybe some code or a screenshot of yours would help to clarify/solve things.

Comment: Thanks Christian, I should have paid more attention to your original answer! I managed to turn off the lights immediately before the DrawArrays call for the points and back on again after. It works perfectly. I wrongly assumed points didn't have orientation. Never assume! Many thanks.